# Calculate date/time difference, return y:m:d h:m:s

Tags: r

Given two date/times:

```
dt_1 <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2016:08:26 11:29:07")
dt_2 <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2016:07:29 09:29:00")
```

How do I calculate the difference from one to the other, and return as output:

```
> "0:0:28 2:0:7"      # 28 days, 2 hours, and 7 seconds difference
```

Using the lubridate approach of:

```
dt_1 - dt_2
```

Returns:

```
> Time difference of 28.08341 days
```

How do I get this output to **y:m:d h:m:s** format? I've searched, but not having any luck!

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE!**

It appears the solution described below by @Sotos and I doesn't quite work. Using the code:

```
dt_1 <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2001:1:1 2:0:0")
dt_2 <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2004:1:1 1:0:0")

paste(
 paste(
 year(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
 month(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
 day(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
sep = ":"),
paste(
 hour(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
 minute(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
 second(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
sep = ":"),
sep = " ")
```

R returns a negative day! "3:0:-1 23:0:0"

For the life of me I cannot work out why this is happening and how to avoid it. The correct answer should be "2:11:30 23:0:0" (or 2 years, 11 months, 30 days, 23 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds).

Any advice?

Comment: Ahh, well that was embarrassingly simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those that are interested. The required output would be returned by running:

```
paste(
 paste(
  year(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
  month(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
  day(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
 sep = ":"),
 paste(
  hour(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
  minute(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
  second(as.period(int_diff(c(dt_2, dt_1)))),
 sep = ":"),
sep = " ")
```

Note that the earlier date/time should always go first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.period` to convert a number to period. From the documents,

> **as.period changes Interval, Duration, difftime and numeric class objects to Period class objects with the specified units**

So you just need to wrap everything in `as.period`, i.e.

```
lubridate::as.period(dt_1 - dt_2)
#[1] "28d 2H 0M 7S"
```